# Hacked bluetooth speaker

Tags: attacks, bluetooth

I recently purchased a new *OontZ Angle Plus* bluetooth speaker and I believe that it has been hacked.

I can't connect any of my devices to it, the bluetooth light indicates that it has been paired with a device, and if I turn my bluetooth on with my computer I will receive never ending messages to connect to an apple mouse (which I don't have, and this will only happen when the speaker is on).

This will happen no matter how often I turn the speaker on and off. It worked for about a week when I first purchased it but no longer.

1. Is it possible to hack this speaker? I'm fairly sure it is.
2. Can I fix it?
3. Can I figure out who is doing it?

The speaker is at my house and to the best of my knowledge my neighbors would not be capable of doing anything like this.

Comment: Why do you believe it has been hacked instead of it simply being faulty?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the speaker was "hacked" :) It could either be a defect or broken speaker, or if you ordered it used from Ebay, it could already be paired. I don't think that your neighbors even know you bought a speaker, and looking online aren't any security problems with that specific speaker.